# coroutine execution problem some coroutines won't launch

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to transform and flush some data to a database in a streaming application using spring and kotlin. performance constraints made me to use coroutine and chunk to execute the transformation and persist procedure faster.
The problem is the size of input data is not equal to the persisted data!

My Job Scheduled to run with a fixed delay:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10_000)
fun flushToDb() {
    // some operations
    CoroutineScope(getDispatcherExec()).launch {
        flush(oldStat, isFlushing)
    }
}
```

and this is my suspend func:

```
private suspend fun flush(oldStat: Map<String, AppDailyStatsModel>, isFlushing: AtomicBoolean) {
    logger.info("RedisFlush ${oldStat.size} starts")
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val count = AtomicLong(0)
    val startCount = AtomicLong(0)
    val newStat = AtomicLong(0)
    val updateStat = AtomicLong(0)
    val input = oldStat.values
    coroutineScope {

        input
                .chunked(1000)
                .forEach { models ->
                    launch {
                        try {
            startCount.addAndGet(models.size.toLong())
                            // Transform

            // Persist
                            count.addAndGet(models.size.toLong())
                            logger.info("Flushed  ${count.get()}")
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            logger.error("PROBLEM IN SAVE ", e)
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

**The issue is `count` and `startCount` are equal and they're less than `input` !!**

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: you may check you wait enough for all launched coroutines to complete. You may add `join` call after the launch function to wait for all activities to complete before checking. It may also be a concurrency in either Map or AppDailyStatsModel class

Comment: @EugenePetrenko coroutineScope make sure that all activities complete and I print out the counters after that.

Comment: @EugenePetrenko what kind of problem? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why use coroutines in the first place, are there any `suspend` functions you're calling? If you just want parallelization, use Java streams. You won't even have to manually chunk the input.

Comment: It seems you let the `@Scheduled` job complete right away. I think Spring expects `flushToIDb` to run until the task is done.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik. do you think changing scope to global fix this problem or the function should be called from somewhere else?

Comment: My first try would be wrapping everything in `runBlocking()`. But, as I already said, i'm not sure what you stand to gain from coroutines in the first place.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah, you're right. I'll try globalScope and if that won't work I'll implement it using java streams